# Smack “NoClassDefFoundError" de/javawi/jstun/util/UtilityException

Tags: java, xmpp

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/javawi/jstun/util/UtilityException
    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.jingle.nat.ICETransportManager.(ICETransportManager.java:33)
    at Model.Main.main(Main.java:31)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.javawi.jstun.util.UtilityException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more

Answer (score 0):

eso sucede cuando te falta una libría en la app, creo que la librería que necesitas la puedes bajar de esta página:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsmackxjingle304jar.htm